# How to undefine/remove a method from a Rails association

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-3

When you define an association in Rails, it creates some methods on that association for you. For example, consider the following:

```
class Person
  has_many :friends
end
```

One of the methods you get is `person.friends.clear`

How can I remove this method such that `person.friends.clear` would raise a `NoMethodError`?

**Note:** I have tried a few things, including `undef_method` and `remove_method` without luck. Please only provide **known** answers and not guesses.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Though I didnt try it myself but could would pls check if the following works

```
has_many :friends do
    def clear 
       raise NoMethodError, "Some reason text"
    end     
end
```

Comment: Yes, this does work. However, I didn't want to manually raise. Something like this would be cool (if it worked): https://gist.github.com/3579574. I might have to though :(

Comment: hmm thats cool. Definitely there are ways... need to try it out myself :)